# Finding maxima or minima of quasilinear function

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

I am trying to optimize function given as $ f(x_k) =\frac{b+mx_k}{c-mx_k}$ with $0 \leq x_k \leq 1$,  $\sum x_k = 1$ , $c-mx_k > 0$ and $b, c, m$ are constants. I am a newbie, as per my understanding, this is is well known fractional function and is quasilinear with only variation in denominator i.e. negative slope $-m$. The graph of function in single dimension is given below. I am puzzled if the function has some unique minima or maxima or some thing else. I would appreciate any help. [function graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RR2q8.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean by $\sum x = 1$? Is there only one variable or more?

Comment: x in my problem represent probabilities and thus its sum is 1 and  m is a constant

Comment: If it's $\sum x_k = 1$, then what's the $x$ in $f(x)$ and $c - mx > 0$?

Comment: Sorry for not being very specific about mathematical notation, I have now edited the equations in an effort to make it more clear.